# HackerRank: ACM ICPC Team

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, programming-challenge, python-3.x

I made a solution to this [problem from HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/acm-icpc-team) :

> You are given a list of **N** people who are attending ACM-ICPC World
>   Finals. Each of them are either well versed in a topic or they are
>   not. Find out the maximum number of topics a 2-person team can know.
>   And also find out how many teams can know that maximum number of
>   topics.
>
> Note Suppose **a, b**, and **c** are three different people, then **(a,b)** and
>   (**b,c)** are counted as two different teams.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> The first line contains two integers, **N** and **M**, separated by a single
>   space, where **N** represents the number of people, and **M** represents the
>   number of topics. **N** lines follow. Each line contains a binary string
>   of length **M**. If the ith line's **jth** character is 1, then the **ith** person
>   knows the **jth** topic; otherwise, he doesn't know the topic.

My code is considered too slow (I think I am allowed 10 seconds, the code below takes more than 20 seconds when N and M are both 500):

```
import random
import itertools
import time

# n number of people
# m number of topics

n = 500
m = 500

"""
binary_string(n) and random_list(n_people, n_topic) just help
to generate test cases, irrelevant otherwise.
"""

def binary_string(n):
    my_string = "".join(str(random.randint(0, 1)) for _ in range(n))
    return my_string    

def random_list(n_people, n_topic):
    my_list = [binary_string(n_topic) for _ in range(n_people)]
    return my_list    

"""
the essential part is item_value(e1, e2)
and find_couples(comb_list)
"""


def item_value(e1, e2):
    c = bin(int(e1, 2) | int(e2, 2))
    return sum(int(i) for i in c[2:])


def find_couples(comb_list):
    max_value = 0
    counter = 0      

    for pair in itertools.combinations(comb_list, 2):
        value = item_value(pair[0], pair[1])
        if value == max_value:
            counter += 1
        elif value > max_value:
            max_value = value
            counter = 1

    print(max_value)
    print(counter)
    return    

topic = random_list(n, m)

print(topic)    

start = time.time()
find_couples(topic)
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

1. In the context of the above algorithm, in what ways can I make it more efficient?
2. Is there a better algorithm?

Comment: Your code is considered too slow you say. How fast is it and how fast does it need to be?

Comment: It would help reviewers to include the sample inputs and outputs here

Comment: @janos On each run, the above code will generate highest order test case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're spending a lot of time in `item_value` converting numbers to a binary string back to an int to get the sum. It would be a lot more expedient to just use `str.count` to get the number of 1s in the string. That saves you a lot of type conversions as well as a call to `sum` with a generator.

```
def item_value(e1, e2):
    c = bin(int(e1, 2) | int(e2, 2))
    return c[2:].count('1')
```

My results from this caused a reduction from 58.9s to 0.91s.

Comment: Thank you. Just out of curiosity, is there a one-liner equivalent of your code?

Comment: @blackened If you really want you could `return bin(int(e1, 2) | int(e2, 2))[2:].count('1')` but that feels cluttered to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you even have to add a comment:

```
# n number of people
```

Just rename `n` to `NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE`, prefer meaningful names over comments, comments may get obsolete as there is no automatic check on them.